# Google Sign In for Google Assistants /// Don´t know how to code it

Tags: actions-on-google

I´m new in dialogflow and I read several tutorials and followed [these instructions](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/how-to-use-google-sign-in-for-the-assistant-b818f3de9211) = I can´t make it!

[Those are my intents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAbwt.png)

We welcome the user and then we ask him if he wants to ask for a song but before running the webhook, we need to ask for his permission to know his name and mail and I don´t realize how to make it work.

This is the index.js

```
// See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
'use strict';
 
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const axios = require('axios');
const https = require('https');


process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
 
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

    function callApi(url, result) {
         return axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: url,
                data: result
         });    
    }

    function welcome(agent) { 
        agent.add(`Bienvenido a la primera playlist armada en comunidad!`);
        agent.add(`¿Querés pedir una canción?`);
        agent.add(new Card({
                    title: 'Yourbans LIVE (by #RockMyPost)!',
                    imageUrl: ‘text.png',
                    text: 'Sé parte de la primera playlist colaborativa 24/7',
                    buttonText: 'Escuchá en VIVO',
                    buttonUrl: 'http://yourbans.com/'
        }));
        agent.add(new Suggestion(`PEDÍ UNA CANCIÓN`));
    }
  
  
    function fallback(agent) {
        agent.add(`¿Podrías repetirlo, por favor?`);
        agent.add(new Suggestion(`PEDÍ UNA CANCIÓN`));
        agent.add(new Card({
                    title: 'Yourbans LIVE (by #RockMyPost)!',
                    imageUrl: ’test.png',
                    text: 'Escuchá en vivo la primera playlist colaborativa 24/7',
                    buttonText: 'Escuchá Yourbans Live',
                    buttonUrl: 'http://yourbans.com/'
            }));
        
    }
  
    function otraCancion(agent) {
        agent.add(`Gracias! Nos vemos pronto.`);
        agent.add(new Card({
                    title: 'Yourbans LIVE (by #RockMyPost)!',
                    imageUrl: ‘test.png',
                    text: 'Escuchá en vivo la primera playlist colaborativa 24/7',
                    buttonText: 'Escuchá Yourbans Live',
                    buttonUrl: 'http://yourbans.com/'
            }));
        
    }
  
    function askSongHandler(agent) {
        const apiUrl = ‘webhook-currentlyworking-perfect’;
        const apikey = ‘xxxxxxx’;
        const song = agent.parameters.song;
        const artist = agent.parameters.artist;
        const hashtag = "#rockmypost";
        const playlist = '#rockmypost';
        const creatorImageUrl = ‘test.png';
        const creator = 'PediUnaCancion';
      
    
        const qtext = hashtag + " " + artist + " + " + song;
        
   
        return callApi(apiUrl, { apikey: apikey, qtext: qtext, playlist: playlist, creatorImageUrl: creatorImageUrl, creator: creator })
        .then((resultados) => {
            //  console.log(resultados.data);
            
          //    agent.add(`Tu canción fue: `+resultados.data.result);
          if (resultados.data.result === 'ACEPTADA'){
            agent.add(`Gracias!`);
            agent.add(`"`+resultados.data.cancion+`"` + ` de ` + resultados.data.artista + ` se agregará a la Playlist y la podrás escuchar a continuación.`);
            agent.add(new Card({
                    title: resultados.data.cancion,
                    imageUrl: resultados.data.urlAlbumImage,
                    text: resultados.data.artista,
                    buttonText: 'Escuchá tu canción!',
                    buttonUrl: 'http://yourbans.com/'
            }));
            agent.add(`¿Querés pedir otro tema?`);
            agent.add(new Suggestion(`PEDÍ OTRA CANCIÓN`));
            
          }
          else {
            agent.add(`Lo siento! Tu tema no fue encontrado.`);
            agent.add(`¿Querés volver a intentarlo?`);
            agent.add(new Suggestion(`PEDÍ UNA CANCIÓN`));
            agent.add(new Card({
                    title: 'Yourbans LIVE (by #RockMyPost)!',
                    imageUrl: ‘test.png',
                    text: 'Escuchá en vivo la primera playlist colaborativa 24/7',
                    buttonText: 'Escuchá Yourbans Live',
                    buttonUrl: 'http://yourbans.com/'
            }));
            
          }
          
          
        })        
        .catch(function (error) {
                agent.add('ERROR' + error);
                console.log('esto es un error',error);
        }); 
    
     
                
      
      
    }

    
    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('PediUnaCancion - yes', askSongHandler);
    intentMap.set('PediUnaCancion - no', otraCancion);
    intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);   
    intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);

  
    
    
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

This is the package.json

```
{
      "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
      "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "private": true,
      "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
      "author": "Google Inc.",
      "engines": {
        "node": "12"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
        "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "actions-on-google": "^2.12.0",
        "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
        "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
        "dialogflow": "^1.2.0",
        "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0",
        "axios-https-proxy-fix": "0.17.1"
       
        
      }
    }
```

This is the last issue to get Google Approval to upload it as an action.
I´m dealing with it since last friday and I´m burned!

Anybody could help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't make it"? If you're having problems with the codelab, it would be helpful to know what those problems are, if you're getting an error, if you don't understand something specific, or what **exactly** your problem is. It doesn't look like you've added any Intents or code to handle the account linking portion. Stack Overflow works best when you try to solve a problem, and we can help you figure out specific problems you're having, rather than general issues. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more.